# How to calculate the histogram of an image in pytorch without for loops

Tags: pytorch, histogram

I'm trying to calculate a histogram of an image with PyTorch without using for loops (or the built in histc function), but just by leveraging the GPU. It should be simple code as this is for students.

Now, since there is a histc function, I assume I could just use that source code. However, I can't seem to find it at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch